# A movie with a cheating time-traveling man

Tags: identify-this-movie

My wife has watched a movie, and she cannot remember the title. I bet with her that I can find that movie.

Known facts:

- No famous actors.
- Movie was not famous.
- Main character was a man, who cheats on his girlfriend, multiple times.
  she found out, so they are so over.
- The man is offered to go back in time, to fix his mistakes.
- He did go back in time, and he finds out that his girlfriend actually does not treat him seriously.
- She cheats on him.
- He dumps her.
- On the last scene, she was offered to go back in time, in order to fix her relationship...
- It was shown in TV in 2003, so its premiere was approximately in '90s.
- Language unknown. :(
- Comedy/drama.

Could you please help me? :)

Comment: Approximate year of release? Country\language? Was it comedic? Dramatic? Suspenseful\scary?

Comment: @Walt : Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question.

Comment: Well, that wasn't an answer, just a comment... But I *am* posting an answer now. ;) Thanks for the extra details.

Comment: *"My wife has watched a movie,.."*  Congratulate her on her ability to recall details!  That was a lot more bullet points than most 'identify this movie' questions.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [The Man with Rain in His Shoes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138590/combined) from 1998, though it does star some recognizable names like Lena Headey, Penelope Cruz and Mark Strong.

> Unfaithful, out-of-work actor Victor is desperate to win back the affection of his ex-girlfriend Sylvia before she marries another man, Dave Summers, but she is resolutely against this. Unexpectedly, he meets two very strange Spanish dust-men who, by means unknown, turn back time and allow him another chance to correct his mistake. However, fate again plays a hand and Dave and Sylvia meet, this time via Sylvia's best friend Alison, and again fall in love. This time around Sylvia is the unfaithful one and eventually leaves Victor to be with Dave.

I'm pretty sure that in the end, *Sylvia* is now the one who turns back time with the help of the same two garbagemen. Also called *'If Only...'* and *'Twice Upon a Yesterday'*. Here's the trailer:

Comment: This is exactly the film I was looking for! Thank you very much. I cannot say how much I admire how you pinpointed that film with so few data.

Much obliged!

Comment: No problem! :) Your question was actually reasonably detailed. So much so that I see another person ID'ed it as well (well done, Yetisasquatch Alienbeliever).